# protect folder contents from being copied

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-permissions

I have several developers in our company and I want them to works on our projects **just on company computers**(computer systems are local).

We want to give them all folder permissions **except copying folder permission**.(projects are protected in gitlab and we don't need delete permission)

is there any way to **disable copying folder permission** or protecting folder and its contents from copying by developers to another computers with **password**?

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Copying is no different than opening. If you can read a file to open it, you can as well write what you've just read to another file.